# What is the correct grammar particle for 'for'?

Tags: grammar

If I want to say, for example,

*I'm waiting **for** Jason*

or

*I'm not in this **for** the money*

What would be the particle? Ni?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent. When it comes to particles and prepositions, you can never expect a one-to-one correspondence. At least に does not work for your examples. Weblio (English-Japanese dictionary for Japanese people learning English) lists [over 20 definitions and over 50 possible translations](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/for) of *for*. The correct particle would be に, へ, の, と or を depending on the sentence.

> I'm waiting for Jason.
>   ジェイソン**を**待っています。
>
> I'm not in this for the money.
>   お金**のために**やっているのではありません。